# SQL Checking if next value is the same or different and write only if it is different

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-order-by, distinct

I am working on sql (TSQL) query to be used for a report (ssrs).
I have a table of a device's values as below (of course there are other fields but these two are important)

```
 device| value
  01      a
  01      a
  01      b
  01      a
  01      b
  01      c
  01      c
  01      c
  01      d
```

And what I would like is to see only different rows but not like distinct
but rather  like

```
 device| value
  01      a
  01      b
  01      a
  01      b
  01      c
  01      d
```

And after that I would write for every user something like path of values using path for xml

```
device |  path 
 01      a - b - a - b - c - d
```

And after that group by path and count number of users

Do you think this is possible?

Comment: It is possible, but you have to tell us how the first query was ordered.

Comment: Define "before" and "after", remember that tables have no inherent ordering so you need an `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: it would be ordered by column DATE that exists in a table

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It doesn't help us help you if you refer to data that you don't show, e.g. a column `DATE` (`NVarChar(MAX)` containing poetry?), something countable called "users" and sample data that never changes (`device` is always `'01'`) but might.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LAG function.

```
SELECT 
 ... 
 , LAG(ValueYouWishToUse, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(OrderByColumnName)) AS PreviousValue
FROM
 ...
WHERE
 ...
```

Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Tilin, this worked like a dream. 